# NullPointerException remove status bar icon

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, nullpointerexception

Right now activity is destroy but status icon still appear on status bar. Can you help me with remove icon in the same time when app is closing? I suspect onDestroy section problem...
LogCat info is that i've got nullpointer exception at line
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);

```
private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_jajko);

text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butStart);

miekko = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butMiekko);
srednio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butSrednio);
twardo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butTwardo);

miekko.setOnClickListener(this);
srednio.setOnClickListener(this);
twardo.setOnClickListener(this);
play.setOnClickListener(this);

mp = MediaPlayer.create(Jajko.this, R.raw.alarm);

showNotification(this);
}


public static void showNotification(Context context) {
    final Intent result_intent = new Intent(context, Jajko.class);

    result_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);



TaskStackBuilder stack_builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stack_builder.addParentStack(Jajko.class);
stack_builder.addNextIntent(result_intent);


PendingIntent pending_intent = stack_builder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

Resources res = context.getResources();
builder.setContentIntent(pending_intent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon))
    .setTicker("test")
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentInfo("cinfo")
    .setContentText("ctext");
Notification n = builder.build();
n.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; 

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


 nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, n);     
}

public void onDestroy() {
try {
    mp.release();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
super.onDestroy();

}
```

**Logcat**

```
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.flex_bak.eggcook/com.example.eggcook.Jajko}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2711)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:121)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:976)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at com.example.eggcook.Jajko.onDestroy(Jajko.java:260)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2680)
09-30 17:24:51.052: E/AndroidRuntime(5200):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: -1 za NPE we własny kodzie! `notificationManager` jest nullem ... a w Twoim kodzie nie ma nic gdzie tą zmienną inicjalizujesz ani deklarujesz ... bez magicznej kuli nie da rady

Comment: @Selvin English please...

Comment: -1 for NPE in own code ... it is pretty obvious that `notificationManager` is `null` ... there is no `notificationManager` initialization (or even declaration) in this code ... OP will understand me since Jajko means Egg :)

Comment: @Selvin I don't understand that last part but maybe because I don't speak whatever that is ;) But that means others won't understand it either. But thank you for the translation, I now know how to say egg in some language

Comment: codeMagic, please show some respect to different cultures. Obviously the op and Selvin are Polish and I would like to great them: Polak, Węgier, dwa bratanki, i do szabli, i do szklanki. I am not a Polish speaker, but a little bit of good willing and respect was enough to understand Selvin's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted, it doesn't look like `notificationManager` is initialized anywhere which certainly would give a `NPE`. I don't even see it being declared but I suppose that is because it is probably done before `onCreate()`, which is fine.

You might have meant `nm` instead of `notificationManage` because you do initialize that. If you think that you did then please show where you think you are initializing it.

You also may check if it is `null` before entering the `if` statement in case it becomes `null` before `onDestroy()` is called.

Comment: I declare in main class private NotificationManager notificationManager; and also initialized NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, n);   at showNoticication() method. Is it wrong? How it should be properly done?

Comment: yes it is wrong becouse it is a local variable. your global one will still be null.

Comment: I've made public NotificationManager notificationManager;
 public static final int NOTIF_ID = 1; and now i have not any bugs but my app status bar icon still appear even if i click back button which should be call destroy method.

Comment: You still don't initialize `notificationManager` that I see.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I declare notificationManager twice: once above onCreate method with public and second time in showNotification() method. Than I try to cancel notify which wasn't really initialized. Thank's for help and open my eyes:)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Just change this line:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

to this

```
nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

and it should work :-)

I think your notificationManager was never initiated or it is already destroyed before you pass onDestroy method.
Include a nullcheck to avoid this exception:

```
public void onDestroy() {
try {
mp.release();
if (isFinishing()) {
if (null != notificationManager)
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
}
super.onDestroy();

}
```